# HTTP Error 403.7 Forbidden - SEFAZ RS

Tags: web-service, nfe, certificado-digital

Estou tentando acessar o [endereço](https://nfe-homologacao.sefazrs.rs.gov.br/ws/NfeAutorizacao/NFeAutorizacao.asmx) de autorização de nota fiscal eletrônica do RS.
Ao acessar recebo a seguinte mensagem:

> Server Error in Application "PRNFH/WS/NFEAUTORIZACAO"
>   HTTP Error 403.7 - Forbidden
>   The page you are attempting to access requires your browser to have a Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) client certificate that the Web server recognizes.

Eu acessei a [página do sefaz RS](https://www.sefaz.rs.gov.br/Site/MontaMenu.aspx?MenuAlias=m_download_nfe), baixei e instalei o [AssinadorRS](https://www.sefaz.rs.gov.br/Site/MontaArquivo.aspx?al=l_dwn_nfe_assinatura_prg) que já vem com um certificado para testes, porém, o certificado que vem junto com ele venceu em 2011.

Eu preciso obter um cetificado digital `quente` para fazer testes de homologação? Ou como eu posso acessar a página de testes do webservice para realizar os testes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para consumir os serviços web da Sefaz (homologação/produção), como [NFe](https://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br) ou [CTe](http://www.cte.fazenda.gov.br/portal/) você vai precisar de um certificado e-CNPJ válido.

No caso do certificado que vem disponibilizado junto com o Assinador, o propósito é de realizar testes para assinar o XML, mas para consumir os [WebServices](http://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/WebServices.aspx) da Sefaz, precisa de um e-CNPJ.